# Docker в Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

Не могу запустить Docker через Jenkins. Установил одноименный плагин - не помогло:

```
+ docker --version
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/PipelineAsCodeExample@tmp/durable-e0ba923d/script.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
```

Я не использую отдельных агентов. Хочу, чтобы докер работал на агенте по умолчанию (на мастере). Что для это нужно сделать?

Comment: У вас загруженный docker контейнер с jenkins  или же вы ставите jenkins в  docker  руками или же просто docker --version через pipeline  делаете?

Comment: Последнее. Я просто поставил дженкинс с плагином пайплайн и докер. В `Jenkinsfile` я делаю `docker --version`.

Comment: А если просто через пайплайн запустить `sh """ docker --version """` работает?

Comment: @nick_gabpe ничего не меняется)

Comment: а если установить docker на хост на котором выполняется sh """ docker --version """?

Answer (score 1):

1. Docker должен быть установлен на самом мастере. Есть ли он в `$PATH` для jenkins пользователя.
2. Проверить права доступа, по умолчанию docker из под sudo только запускается.
3. Рассмотреть вариант запуска через Jenkinsfile.